# grep multiple values but only a specific column

Tags: awk, grep

I have two files, targets.txt and huge.txt. Huge.txt is a tab-delimited file with 50m lines, all numbers. Targets.txt contains a list of 100,000 values (also all numbers) that I want to search for in huge.txt but only in a specific column. If I match any column I will get false positives because I might have a number match for a column other than the on I am interested in.

I can use something like:

```
awk '$3==someval' huge.txt
```

I don't want to do a for loop given the size of targets.txt and run awk many times an >> into an output file since that's O(n^2). Is there any way to use grep -F where I instruct grep to only look in, say, column 3?

In the output I want the full lines from huge.txt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiomatic way with `awk` is storing the small file in an array and looking up in the large file.

For example,

```
awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} $3 in a' Target.txt Huge.txt
```

100k numbers may be large for your memory, if so you can split Target.txt into chunks, run multiple of these and merge results.  For a modern computer it shouldn't be a problem though.

Comment: Interestingly this works for all columns in huge.txt except for the last column. It refuses to match values in column $NF no matter what I do. So if I do:

awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} $NR in a' target.txt huge.txt

it never matches. But that code works fine if I replace $NR with $1 through $N-1 with N columns

Comment: `NR` is the line number, the last field is `$NF`

Comment: typo - thank you. For some reason I still cannot get it to work with the last row